# Docker, csf and mariadb connection

Tags: docker, mariadb, csf

I have a host with csf firewall allowing some external ports like ssh, http, https.

I have now installed docker and mariadb through docker. I use docker run command with `-p 6000:3306`, so that means that docker exposes mariadb port in 6000.

I try `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port 6000 -u root -ppass` but seems it cannot connect. If I stop csf it connects.

So how can I unblock all local connections from csf to docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

Running docker behind a firewall isn't that obvious. Docker tries to change the `iptables` rules. To allow this edit your `/etc/csf/csf.conf` and change the `DOCKER` option to `1` or use the UI:
[image]

Be careful because `-p 6000:3306` will expose the ports for the whole world. If you want to expose it for only local usage, try `-p 127.0.0.1:600:3306`.